# CLI package to replace Plesk

Tags: command-line-interface

Myself and another programmer are tasked with maintaining a few webservers. I prefer CLI tools, she prefers Plesk. However, I am adamant about not installing Plesk for quite a few reasons.

I have written a small Python script for adding new domains, and now I am about to add the ability to configure email addresses while abstracting the details of Postfix from her. Before I go that route, I have googled to see if anything already exists, and am surprised that I have come up with nothing! Are there any mature, stable "control panels" or "server admin" tools like Plesk, but which are accessed via the CLI over SSH? I am looking for the following features:

- Add / remove / configure domains served by Apache.
- Add / remove / configure email boxes and mail groups.
- Add / remove MySQL databases, users, and configure users to databases.
- Provide basic monitoring of "server health", that is: memory usage, disk usage, CPU usage, bandwidth usage.
- Possibly set up STFP accounts so that only specific FTP users could access specific `/var/www/someSite/` directories.

Comment: This looks like a shopping question really.

Comment: Thanks, Iain. I did look and don't see any "do" or "don't" regarding if asking for software suggestions are allowed or not. The only problem might be in the 'opinion' part of the question. I have addressed that.

Comment: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/

Comment: Thanks, Iain, great link! Actually, I have already addressed that issue without even knowing it. The section that starts `However, there is a way to ask these questions that avoids the inherent problems with shopping recommendations.` suggests to word the question exactly as I have worded it, in order to avoid the "shopping recommendation" experience. I will be sure to consciously do that in future questions as well. Thank you!

Comment: Your junior admin has to start learning how to be a sysadmin _sometime_. Why not now?

Comment: Because that is not her job. She is a web developer who is my backup in case I'm sick. We're a small, growing shop and it will be some time before there is enough income for another system admin.

Comment: Seeing how nothing exists, I'm starting my own [CLI-based web server control panel](https://github.com/dotancohen/burton). I would love nothing more than to have this community's feedback, ideas, and suggestions. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

There are no such tools, as those who graduate beyond point-and-click to CLI don't need them and usually don't want them. Add/remove domains is a matter of adding a file, email boxes should be as simple as editing a file (or ldap), mysql users and databases are added with a single command.

Why would you replace domain knowledge (as in: *knowing* the tools you work with) with a dumbed down version like a control panel that will force you to work its way? I see the point if you're a bit junior and want something nice and point-and-clicky, but not when you actually know how to use your OS.

Comment: The reason is that multiple people with different levels of competency need to administrate this server. I prefer editing `/etc/apache2/sites-available`, but the other admin who needs to admin the server doesn't know how to do that. Imparting _all_ my knowledge on her in wiki form is impractical. Nor can our little shop take on board another employee at the moment.

Comment: Then maybe you should stick with a controlpanel-ish solution. Or use puppet to set up some recipes and make it really easy for them to edit those recipes to do the actions you want them to do.